# Undefined variable: state which results in undefined no object at if rowcount

Tags: php, authentication, pdo

Yesterday, the script worked just fine, when I fill in the correct information i still get redirected, but when not I got the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: state in C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop\resources\library\login.class.php on line 26
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop\resources\library\login.class.php on line 26

```
<?php
        require_once('../resources/config.php');
        class user
        {
            private $db;

            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->db = new config();
                $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect(); 
            }

            public function login($name, $pass)
            {
                if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass))
                {
                //parameter query to prevent sql injection
                $state = $this->db->prepare("select * from users where name=? and pass=?");
                $state->bindParam(1, $name);
                $state->bindParam(2, $pass);
                $state->execute();
                }



                if($state->rowCount() == 1)
                {
                        header('location: index?page=basket.php');
                        echo "you have been loged in as <b>$dbuser</b>";


                    }else{

                        echo "incorrect user";
                    }




            }
        }

        ?>
```

usage

```
<?php
require_once('../resources/library/login.class.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        $obj_login = new user();
        $obj_login->login($name, $pass);
    }   
?>

<form method="post" action="index.php?page=login.php">
    username: <input type="text" name="user"/>
    password: <input type="text" name="pass"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

could anybody please guide me though?

Answer (score 1):

If either `$name` or `$pass` is empty, `$state` is not defined (due to your `if`-statement). Later you assume `$state` is present and you try to access its methods.

This results in your error.

The most easy fix is to move `if($state->rowCount() == 1)` and its 'true'-branch right after the `$state->execute()`, so the state is only checked if it got executed.

If the user got logged in, return from the function. So you can leave `echo "incorrect user";` to handle the case(s) when the login failed.

```
public function login($name, $pass)
{
    if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass))
    {
        //parameter query to prevent sql injection
        $state = $this->db->prepare("select * from users where name=? and pass=?");
        $state->bindParam(1, $name);
        $state->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $state->execute();

        if($state->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            header('location: index?page=basket.php');
            // do NOT output content after you set this header!
            // echo "you have been loged in as <b>$dbuser</b>";
            return true;
        }
    }
    echo "incorrect user";
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont define `$state` when either name or pass are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this on the login PHP code:

```
require_once('../resources/config.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that `user::login()` only prepares the statement if both `$name` and `$pass` are not empty. However, if they are the code still tries to execute the statement. Obviously at that point in the condition the statement object was never instantiated and that's why you get the error.

You can fix this by simply checking that the username and password aren't empty at the time the request is submitted. One minor, suggestion is also to **not** rely on a value to tell you the **HTTP request method** used in the request. I would highly recommend you not rely on that behavior, especially since some browsers are known to not send the value of the submit input type at all. Instead use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to determine if the request method is `POST` or `GET` (unless you don't care, but in your form the request method is set to `post` so I assume you do). Additionally, you don't need to copy $_POST variables into another variable just to pass them to your object's method. That's a waste. You also can access super global variables like $_POST from any scope in your code (*just as an FYI*).

```
<?php
require_once('../resources/library/login.class.php');

if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST')
    {
        if (empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass']))
            {
                echo "Please supply a username and password!";
            } else {
                $obj_login = new user();
                $obj_login->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);
            }
    }   
?>

<form method="post" action="index.php?page=login.php">
    username: <input type="text" name="user"/>
    password: <input type="text" name="pass"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```